# Convert H:M:S into minutes in a new variable in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a time variable in H:M:S format, and I would like to make a new variable that converts this to only minutes.
Ie - 1:30:00 in a new variable will be recorded as 90.

This is what I was using, but isn't running, any suggestions?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
DF <- c("1:00:00", "1:30:00", "00:45:00")
Time <- hms(DF)
DFTime <- Time %>% mutate(TimeMins = hour(Time)*60 + mins(Time))
head(DFTime$TimeMins)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `as_hms` from `hms`

```
library(hms)
as.numeric(as_hms(v1))/60
[1] 60 90 45
```

---

or using `base R`

```
rowSums((read.table(text = v1, sep=":", header = FALSE) * list(3600, 60, 0))/60)
[1] 60 90 45
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("1:00:00", "1:30:00", "00:45:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `as.Time` function (in the `data.table` package) and the built-in function `as.integer`:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- c("1:00:00", "1:30:00", "00:45:00")

as.integer(as.ITime(DF) %/% 60L)
# [1] 60 90 45
```

**Note:** The decimal part of the converted time is dropped!!

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 changes to your code:

- I use `minute` function from `lubridate` instead of `mins`
- I convert Time to data frame so that the `mutate` function can work

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
DF <- c("1:00:00", "1:30:00", "00:45:00")
Time <- data.frame(Time = hms(DF))
DFTime <- Time %>% mutate(TimeMins = hour(Time)*60 + minute(Time))
head(DFTime$TimeMins)

# results
# [1] 60 90 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `asPOSIXlt` in R base.

```
tt <- as.POSIXlt(paste(Sys.Date(), x))
rowSums(mapply(\(x, y) unclass(tt)[[x]]*y/60, 1:3, c(0, 60, 60^2)))
# [1] 60 90 45
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("1:00:00", "1:30:00", "00:45:00")
```